# ggplot multiple binary variables, grouped by another binary varaible

Tags: r, ggplot2, count, binary, bar-chart

Hi so I have a number of binary variables something like this. I want to visualize the count for each of the bar variables and group them via the result in the group variable all in one ggplot bar chart. Given that the responses to the bar variables are not mutually exclusive I can't just recode them into a categorical variable, which is where I'm coming into some issues.

| bar 1 | bar 2 | bar 3 | groups |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want this?

```r
df <- read.table(header = T, text = "bar1   bar2    bar3    groups
1   0   1   1
1   1   1   0
1   1   0   0
1   0   1   1")

library(tidyverse)

df %>% pivot_longer(starts_with('bar')) %>%
  group_by(groups, name) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x = name, y = value, fill = as.factor(groups)), position = 'dodge')
```

[image]

---

If you want to remove 0s use filter

```r
df %>% pivot_longer(starts_with('bar')) %>%
  group_by(groups, name) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  filter(value != 0) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x = name, y = value, fill = as.factor(groups)), position = 'dodge')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you that was really helpful. Any idea how to remove NAs from both the group and the bar variables in the plot? I've tried a few different things with no luck.

Comment: Which NAs?  You mean 0s?

Comment: No my real data has actual "NA"s as in missing values. Sorry should have shown that in the example

Comment: use `na.rm = T` in that case while summarising, as `summarise(value = sum(value, na.rm =T), .groups = 'drop') %>%` in third line